# How to generate a new column with constant values based on the row counts

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
TS         Col1
00:00:00   12
00:00:01   07
00:00:02   18
00:00:03   54
00:00:04   25
00:00:05   05
```

And I want to create a new column with constant values(starting from 1 to n) for every two records sequentially as given below.

```
TS         Col1  New
00:00:00   12    1
00:00:01   07    1
00:00:02   18    2
00:00:03   54    2
00:00:04   25    3
00:00:05   05    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by a range of numbers (created by `np.arange(len(df))`) and then get group number with `.ngroup()` function:

```
df['New'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).ngroup() + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         TS  Col1  New
0  00:00:00    12    1
1  00:00:01     7    1
2  00:00:02    16    2
3  00:00:03    54    2
4  00:00:04    25    3
5  00:00:05     5    3
```